# Issues with blank text being added to array

Tags: uitableview, swift, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a text field in my app that users use to enter names for budgets. I am storing these names in an array so that the user can tap a 'preset' button to quickly access previously used names.

If the user does not enter a budget name then the name is just set as 'Budget' automatically, and I do not want to store this in the preset list. Therefore, I came up with this code:

```
    presetNames = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("presets") as NSArray
    presetNamesMutable = presetNames.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray

    if presetNamesMutable.containsObject(budgetName) == false && budgetName != "Budget" {
        presetNamesMutable.insertObject(budgetName, atIndex: 0)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(presetNamesMutable, forKey: "presets")
    }
```

So basically it checks to make sure the name is not already in the array and that the name is not 'Budget'.

The problem is that for some reason if the text field is left blank, rather than ignoring it and not adding it to the array, it seems to just add "" to the array. I can't figure out why...

This is an example of what I mean:

[image]

Here is the rest of the code:

Table View for displaying the preset names:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return presetNamesMutable.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:PresetTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as PresetTableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...

    cell.presetNameLabel.text = presetNamesMutable.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

    tempBudgetName = presetNamesMutable.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as String
    presetTapped = true
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(presetTapped, forKey: "presetUsed")
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    println(tempBudgetName)
}


// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    presetNamesMutable.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(presetNamesMutable, forKey: "presets")
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    presetNames = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("presets") as NSArray
    presetNamesMutable = presetNames.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was obvious in the code that I posted in my question. I had just changed it from:

```
if presetNamesMutable.containsObject(budgetName) == false && budgetNameLength != 0 {
```

To:

```
if presetNamesMutable.containsObject(budgetName) == false && budgetName != "Budget" {
```

So I had completely missed the fact that I wasn't setting the name to 'Budget'. It is now fixed with this code:

```
    presetNames = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("presets") as NSArray
    presetNamesMutable = presetNames.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray

    if budgetNameLength == 0 {
        budgetName = "Budget"
    }

    if presetNamesMutable.containsObject(budgetName) == false && budgetName != "Budget" {
        presetNamesMutable.insertObject(budgetName, atIndex: 0)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(presetNamesMutable, forKey: "presets")

        println(presetNamesMutable)
    }
```